# _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-window"

Tags: python, tkinter

I tumbled upon this Error when I tried putting a frame into my window with the following source codes:

`frame=tkinter.Frame(window="relief",relief="ridge",borderwith=20)`

and I got this Error:
`_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-window"`
maybe I passed in wrong arguments,but I just don't know what to pass in...

Comment: It is not `window`, it is `master`

Comment: Any basic documentation or even code samples on Stack Overflow would have had the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the parameters. The first parameter is the widget where you want to add you Frame. Check the example below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import tkk

#This is your root
root = Tk()
root.title('Example App')

#Here you add the frame to the root
mainFrame = ttk.Frame(root)
```

In this case we put the Frame whithin the root.

Comment: Why are you using `ttk.Frame` when OP used `tk.Frame`? That might confuse them. Also where did `relief="ridge",borderwith=20` go?